# how find list of file by batch file

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

I need a batch file to find all of my *.sql file in specefic folder and its subfolder like "c:\aaa\" and by using xcopy copy the latest version of them on other folder like "c:\bbb\"

would you help me?

I use windows xp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your command prompt:

`C:\>for /R c:\aaa %G IN (*.sql) DO xcopy "%G" C:\bbb\`

It recurses through c:\aaa\ and its subfolders and copies the found *.sql files to c:\bbb (without the original folder structure).